# Jhipster Error in running server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using jhipster-4.5.1 with h2 database, I am getting error in running server after changing the code, but there is no error in codes but only error I am getting in running server when code modifies.it says

```
2017-06-14 17:43:03.578  WARN 19964 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bloodPressureResource' defined in file [/home/rajeev/Devapp_Maven/target/classes/com/devapp/web/rest/BloodPressureResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bloodPressureRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.devapp.repository.BloodPressureRepository.findAllByTimestampBetweenOrderByTimestampDesc(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)!
2017-06-14 17:43:03.916 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-com.devapp.domain.Points   : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.919 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-com.devapp.domain.Weight   : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.921 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.devapp.domain.BloodPressure      : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.923 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.devapp.domain.Preferences        : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.925 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.devapp.domain.Authority          : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.930 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.core.Ehcache-com.devapp.domain.User  : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.932 DEBUG 19964 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.devapp.domain.User.authorities   : Close successful.
2017-06-14 17:43:03.994  WARN 19964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cache-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@60ee6558 has not been refreshed yet)
2017-06-14 17:43:04.016 ERROR 19964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bloodPressureResource' defined in file [/home/rajeev/Devapp_Maven/target/classes/com/devapp/web/rest/BloodPressureResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bloodPressureRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.devapp.repository.BloodPressureRepository.findAllByTimestampBetweenOrderByTimestampDesc(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)!
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please format the code, extract the error and try to precisely describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query `findAllByTimestampBetweenOrderByTimestampDesc` within `BloodPressureRepository` is invalid.

That's what's being told in that error at least:

`Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.devapp.repository.BloodPressureRepository.findAllByTimestampBetweenOrderByTimestampDesc(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)!`

Comment: How should I change it,not getting any other method?and How to modify query---- @Query("select blood_pressure from BloodPressure blood_pressure where blood_pressure.manytoone.login = ?#{principal.username} order by BloodPressure.Date desc")

Comment: Thats code---
public interface BloodPressureRepository extends JpaRepository<BloodPressure, Long> {
 //@Query("select * from BloodPressure")
 @Query("select blood_pressure from BloodPressure blood_pressure where blood_pressure.manytoone.login = ?#{principal.username} order by BloodPressure.Date desc")
 List<BloodPressure> findAllByTimestampBetweenAndUserLoginOrderByTimestampDesc(LocalDate firstDate, LocalDate secondDate);
 List<BloodPressure> findAllByTimestampBetweenAndUserLoginOrderByTimestampDesc(LocalDate daysAgo, LocalDate rightNow, String login);
}

Comment: If you would add that code (properly formatted) to your question someone might be able to help you. I never used that `@Query` syntax `?#{principal.userName}` butmaybe it doesn't know how to find the `principal`. Maybe you need to add it to the arguments and specify `@Param("principal")`?

Comment: I just found https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions using `?#{principal.emailAddress}` .. so that might work, too. Maybe you need to update your question.